# "Sorting not supported for current query." error when sorting List members API

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-sdks

I keep getting the above error when try to sort the list on displayName, however sorting is clearly supported according the example below: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-3

I tried adding ConsistencyLevel headers and count query param with no luck.

```
var users = await GraphHelper.client.Users
    .Request() //new List<QueryOption>() { new QueryOption("$count","true") }
    .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
    .Filter($"accountEnabled eq true and extension_{AppConfig.variable["B2C:ExtensionId"]}_BankId eq '{bankId}'")
    .OrderBy("displayName")
    .Select($"id,displayName,identities,extension_{AppConfig.variable["B2C:ExtensionId"]}_BankId").GetAsync();
```

[image]

Same query works in graph explorer but not in the REST API.

[image]

Comment: Do you use beta or v1.0 endpoint?

Comment: Have you tested it in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) or POSTMAN?

Comment: A guess  -- order by is throwing exception as extension property is used in filter clause?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I tried in Graph Explorer `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$search="displayName:wa"&$orderby=displayName` works but `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=accountEnabled%20eq%20true&$orderby=displayName` returns `Request_UnsupportedQuery`

Comment: @user1672994 Thanks, that was the first thing I tried, but no luck. Seems to be related to $filter. $search seems to work fine in the graph explorer.

Comment: @ChrisGunawardena - I checked that and notice that filters works with beta version currently when used by `orderby` but throws error with 1.0 version.

Comment: @user1672994 Actually when I add the `$count=true` the graph explorer works as intended but still fails when I git the API directly. Maybe it's related to B2C. I added an updated screenshot of the two.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are seeing this discrepancy because of incorrect setup in POSTMAN and code.

You can setup **POSTMAN** by following this [step-by-step guide](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/30daysmsgraph-day-13-postman-to-make-microsoft-graph-calls/). A quick glance of steps is below:

- Registering the Azure AD App
- Get admin consent for the app
- Get access token using the app
- Make Microsoft Graph API call using the access token as bearer token

Similarly, please check similar setup of C# code as well.

---

#### **Edit:**

It seems there are [some rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters) that we need to follow while using `filter` and `orderby`:

[image]

Hence, when I followed the rules and ran `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$filter=startsWith(displayName,'B')&$orderby=displayName desc` query, it works:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's the case because if I don't send $filter or $orderby params I get valid results as you can see in this vdeo https://www.loom.com/share/b956fbf89c834650b1c2bc72536aa867

Comment: Thanks, the exact query doesn't work for me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IeRJ.png but again works without orderby https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZO1k.png 

Maybe there is a difference between the graph explorer and the deployed version OR it's something to do with my token (which I added to the answer)?

Comment: Pls remove PII information from question.

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, as per my comment above,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IeRJ.png is the same example as the one you gave, this query works in graph explorer but no via postman.

Comment: You mentioned above that my exact query was not working for you in graph explorer also, is that a correct understanding?

Comment: No, it's working  in graph explorer like you demonstrated. Maybe it's b2c related.

Comment: Yes, then cross verify credentials and permissions once.

Comment: Well, it works without the orderBy param, so it's probably a bug with Graph API. I'm just going to do the sorting manually.

Comment: If you think it is a bug, I would reach out to the PG and report it.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a reference in your code sample to B2C-ExtensionID. Not all of the core Microsoft Graph calls play nicely with B2C tenants.

The most recent MS documentation I've found is from 1/26/21 and can be [viewed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations)

The documentation does not make clear some information I consider rather important for those of us working with B2C. Little comments like this one, found in the Optional query parameters section of [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) :

> The $count and $search parameters are currently not available in Azure AD B2C tenants.

It is also worth noting that, since B2C doesn't support $count, the presently MS endorsed workaround (which requires using $count, along with a header of "ConsistencyLevel: eventual") for using $orderby cannot be used against a list of B2C users.

So, if you're using Microsoft Graph to work with B2C tenant data you cannot implement useful features like counting your api resposne results, nor can you order them.